# вывод результата в окне PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Как выводить результат в главное окно? Сделал выбор и по нажатию кнопки у меня происходит вывод в терминал результата моей функции, а как сделать вывод в это окно или пусть новое , какой виджет создавать?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class stackedExample(QWidget):

    def do_leftbar(self):
        self.leftlist.insertItem(0, 'Сравнение справочников')               # insertItem(позиция в списке, текст)
        self.leftlist.insertItem(1, 'Редактирование справочников')
        # self.leftlist.insertItem(2, 'Будущий функционал')


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.leftlist = QListWidget()
        self.do_leftbar()


        self.stack1 = QWidget()
        self.stack2 = QWidget()

        self.stack1UI()
        self.stack2UI()

        self.Stack = QStackedWidget(self)

        self.Stack.addWidget(self.stack1)    # возвращает индекс виджета addWidget
        self.Stack.addWidget(self.stack2)



        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)   # расположение макета
        hbox.addWidget(self.leftlist)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Stack)

        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.leftlist.currentRowChanged.connect(self.display)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.gooo)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('StackedWidget demo')
        self.show()

    def gooo(self):
        if(self.L1.isChecked()):
            print("L1 tyt my_function")
        elif (self.L2.isChecked()):
            print("L2")
        elif (self.L3.isChecked()):
            print("L3")
        else:
            print("select")
    def stack1UI(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        face = QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton("GO")
        self.L1 = QRadioButton("L1")
        self.L2 = QRadioButton("L2")
        self.L3 = QRadioButton("L3")
        face.addWidget(self.L1)
        face.addWidget(self.L2)
        face.addWidget(self.L3)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("select"), face)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.stack1.setLayout(layout)


    def stack2UI(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        self.stack2.setLayout(layout)

    def display(self,i):
        print(i)
        self.Stack.setCurrentIndex(i)


class great(QMainWindow, QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        a = stackedExample()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 900)
        self.setCentralWidget(a)
        self.show()


def main():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = stackedExample()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пример, который у вас есть.

Comment: ну то есть я проверяю выбранные параметры и потом там буду вызывать функцию которая вернет результат и как выводить в окно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я предлагаю добавить виджет `QTextEdit()` и туда все выводить.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class StackedExample(QWidget):                    # StackedExample
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.leftlist = QListWidget()
        self.do_leftbar()

        self.stack1 = QWidget()
        self.stack2 = QWidget()

        self.stack1UI()
        self.stack2UI()

        self.Stack = QStackedWidget(self)

        self.Stack.addWidget(self.stack1)    # возвращает индекс виджета addWidget
        self.Stack.addWidget(self.stack2)


        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)             # расположение макета
        hbox.addWidget(self.leftlist)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Stack)

        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.leftlist.currentRowChanged.connect(self.display)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.gooo)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('StackedWidget demo')


    def do_leftbar(self):
        # insertItem(позиция в списке, текст)
        self.leftlist.insertItem(0, 'Сравнение справочников')               
        self.leftlist.insertItem(1, 'Редактирование справочников')
        # self.leftlist.insertItem(2, 'Будущий функционал')

    def gooo(self):
        if(self.L1.isChecked()):
            text = "L1 tyt my_function"                            # text
        elif (self.L2.isChecked()):
            text = "L2"
        elif (self.L3.isChecked()):
            text = "L3"
        else:
            text = "select"

        self.textEdit.append(text)                                 # <--- append

    def stack1UI(self):

        label = QLabel("select")
        self.L1 = QRadioButton("L1")
        self.L2 = QRadioButton("L2")
        self.L3 = QRadioButton("L3")
        face = QHBoxLayout()
        face.addWidget(label)
        face.addWidget(self.L1)
        face.addWidget(self.L2)
        face.addWidget(self.L3)

        self.button = QPushButton("GO")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()                                # + textEdit

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(face)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)

        self.stack1.setLayout(layout)

    def stack2UI(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        self.stack2.setLayout(layout)

    def display(self,i):
        print(i)
        self.textEdit.append(f'currentRowChanged -> {i}')
        self.Stack.setCurrentIndex(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    demo = StackedExample()
    demo.resize(600, 400)
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Venot я очень рекомендую вам прочитать https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions